# What is the meaning of 亲收获？

Tags: translation, idioms, slang

What is the meaning of

> 亲收获？

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. What is the context?

Comment: What have you tried? Translation questions where no research effort has been indicated are off-topic: we're not here to provide a translation service.

Comment: Are you sure that that these are the correct characters? 亲 also means 'personally' or 'in person'. See if now it makes sense. Otherwise, without context it's hard to translate.

Comment: 新收获 （e。g。＂new  acquisitions＂）would make sense and removing right-hand component 斤 from 新 with left-right structure would result in 亲收获，＂新收获＂具有意义而且从属左右结构的＂新＂汉字取出其右边部件＂斤＂之后，剩下文字就是＂亲收获 ＂

Answer (score 1):

This sentence (亲收获) does not make any sense.

The closest thing I can think of is "亲，收货", which means "Hey there, pick up your package."

Note that "亲" originally mean "darling", but among contemporary Chinese Internet users, it has very weak emotion and only means "hey there", especially on Taobao, an eBay-like website.

Comment: Yep. It is defenitely 亲，收货 on Taobao.